# Project Euler problems 18/67: maximum path sum

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge

I recently solved problems 18/67 in Project Euler. My code is long and I think it could be more effective. I solved the problem with dynamic programming and am new to it, so I want to improve my dynamic programming.  I think my running time is acceptable: 0.214 seconds.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EighteenNSixtyseven {
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public ArrayList<ArrayList> readFile() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> nodeList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Triangle.txt"));
        String tmp = reader.readLine();
        while (tmp != null) {
            String[] nums = tmp.split("\\s+");
            ArrayList<Integer> nmb = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                nmb.add(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]));
            }
            nodeList.add(nmb);
                                     // im adding an ArrayList to the ArrayList
            tmp = reader.readLine();    // where the first ArrayList index is the 
        }                                // the specific row and the other ArrayList
                                        // containing the numbers
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return nodeList;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EighteenNSixtyseven ad = new EighteenNSixtyseven();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  // starting time
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")               // eclipse suggested this??? Why?
    ArrayList<ArrayList> list = ad.readFile(); // reading the file with numbers in triangle
    int size = list.size() - 1;
    int calc = 0;
    int otherCalc = 0;
    int q = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> temp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (size >= 1) {
        temp1 = list.get(size);
        temp2 = list.get(size - 1);
        q = 0;
        if (temp2.size() != 1) {
            while (q < temp2.size() - 1) {
                for (int k = 0; k < temp2.size(); k++) {    // checking which    
                    calc = temp1.get(q) + temp2.get(k);        // sum gives the bigger on
                    otherCalc = temp1.get(q + 1) + temp2.get(k); // adding numbers
                    if (calc > otherCalc) {                        // in the lower line
                        temp2.set(k, calc);                    // with the ones in the line
                    } else {                                // over to the right and left
                        temp2.set(k, otherCalc);
                    }
                    q++;
                }
                size--;
            }
        } else {
            calc = temp1.get(0) + temp2.get(0);            // had to add this or the
            otherCalc = temp1.get(1) + temp2.get(0);    // array is outOufBounds
            if (calc > otherCalc) {
                temp2.set(0, calc);
                size--;
            } else {
                temp2.set(0, otherCalc);
                size--;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe sum total is = " + temp2.get(0));
    long elapsedTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    float elapsedTimeSec = elapsedTimeMillis / 1000F;
    System.out.println("Tid " + elapsedTimeSec);
}
}
```

As you can see, the code is a bit messy! Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Even before starting the review I have to disappoint you. The problem has nothing to do with the dynamic programming. Now let's go.

1. **Naming**: Avoid meaningless names, such as `q`, `temp1`, `temp2`, `calc` and `otherCalc`.
2. **Responsibilities**: You correctly separated IO in a method of its own. The actual calculations also deserve to be separated.
3. **Algorithm**: A triple nesting loop is an immediate red flag. In fact, you don't need to iterate over `q` (which is the index into the bottom row, right? - it took me a while to figure it out) at all: the `k`th element of the upper row can be only influenced by `k`th and `k+1`th of the bottom one. Taking it into consideration, you'd eliminate one level of nesting as well as a really ugly special case of `temp2.size() == 1`.

The core loop should look like

```
    for (k = 0; k < upperRow.size(); k++)
            upperRow[k] += max(bottomRow[k], bottomRow[k+1]);
```

That said, let me reiterate a very important rule of *no raw loops*: for every loop you write, think of it as a standalone method and figure out a meaningful name for it. If you can't than you effectively don't know what it is doing!

Comment: yup no DP but weighted shortest path :) The title says it all "path"

Answer (score 7):

### Architecture

Instances of this class don't represent anything, so there shouldn't be any. It should be a fake class with only static methods, like `java.Math`.

### Variables

Many variable scopes are too large. Variables should be declared where they're initialized, not declared in one place and initialized later.

Variable names should indicate their meaning:

- `nodeList` and `list` are the `triangle`.
- `temp1` is `nextRow`, and `temp2` is `currentRow`.
- `calc` and `otherCalc` are the costs of the left and right paths from this node. (But they should both go away.)
- `size` is `currentDepth` or the `y` coordinate.

Several `while` loops could be written as `for` loops to make the initialization and updating of their loop variables obvious.

### readFile

Don't suppress the `rawtypes` warning — it's telling you something! `nodeList` should be an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

You only need one call to `readLine`: `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` is the idiomatic way to read lines in Java.

The string-parsing loop can be over elements, not indexes: `for (String s : nums)`.

Don't catch `Exception`. Catch only the exception you expect, in this case `java.io.IOException`. (Ideally you shouldn't catch any exception you can't handle — just let them propagate to the caller — but Java forces you to catch some exceptions. Fortunately in this case you only need one `catch`, not two.)

### main

Overwriting the triangle with its maximum path costs is confusing, because it changes the meaning of the data structure partway through. It would be cleaner to use a separate data structure for the path costs.

There's no reason to duplicate the section that adds path costs.

The nested loops on `k` and `q` do the same thing. You probably only want one of them. (I think this causes a bug, too.)

The `if (calc > otherCalc) ... calc ... else otherCalc` pattern can be written more simply as `Math.max(calc, otherCalc)`.

Comment: First of all big thank you! You said i could write for (String s : nums) instead of for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     rowNmbs.add(Integer.parseInt(nums[i]));                                                                but when i dont have my i how do i tell what index to add? what do i typ in the "box" in nums[]? What is the difference between java.io.IOException and Exception? The other things i understand!

Comment: "It should be a fake class with only static methods..." The technical term is "(static) utility class".

Comment: You don't need an index when you already have the element: `for (String s : nums) { row.add(Integer.parseInt(s)); }`. [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is the subclass of `Exception` for I/O failures; catching it avoids catching other exceptions you didn't expect, like `NumberFormatException` from `parseInt`.

Comment: @Bobby: I wanted to make it clear that it was a class serving as a module, not a class for utility purposes.